# java-script validation on text box for already existing condition

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net

I want to do this type of validation using javascript on text box  in asp.net on textchange event of text box  below is my code in c# validtaion:

```
string str = "Select ReceiptNo from BranchOutwardItems where ReceiptNo='" + txtReceiptNo.Text + "'";

DataTable dt = objGlobalClass.LoadData(str);
if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
     lblMsg.Text = " Receipt ID already exists.Click On ADD for Generate New Receipt ID";
}
else
{
     lblMsg.Text = "Receipt ID doesnot exists";
}
```

Comment: STOP using dynamic Query

Comment: You want to do a db call every time the text changes?

Comment: why not just use ajax update panel

Comment: This is not a good idea becuase: 1. javascript validation could be eliminated easily; 2. the code given is a good candidate for SQL injection.

Comment: You should use focus out. Because you are going to hit the database for each character change. Your will have to create a Web-Service or page method or http-handler which takes the value from java-script and return the appropriate message.

Answer (score 1):

For this you will have to call a Page-Method or A Web-Service, Or a Http-Handler to validate the value of the text box.

Here is a similar [example](http://sappidireddy.wordpress.com/2008/03/31/how-to-call-server-side-function-from-client-side-code-using-pagemethods-in-aspnet-ajax/) 
Here too is a good [example](http://weblogs.asp.net/karan/archive/2010/09/12/calling-server-side-method-using-jquery-ajax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
var tbl = document.getElementById('tblID');
var lbl = document.getElementById('lblID');
if(tbl != null)
{

if(tbl.rows.length > 0)
{
lbl.innerHTML = "Success Message";
}
else 
{
lbl.innerHTML = "Failed Message";

}

}
```